# How to fill the input controls in Web Browser using C++?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have SmartCard Reader which can read a National ID Card, but in the SDK and Sample project that it use to read is a using Boland C++ Project using C++.

My product is a web application and have a form providing to user fill in and run it only in Internet Explorer 7,8.

How to use C++ to fill a web form in the Web Browser

Comment: What web browser? The answer will inherently be different depending on which browser you're targeting.

Comment: Are you suggesting to have the form automatically populated by the smart card reader?

Comment: @Billy The web browser is Internet Explorer 7, 8.

Comment: @set Yes, I wanna fill the form in web application using smart card reader.

Comment: @Noppol: I don't believe that functionality is exposed by Internet Explorer. You'd have to write some sort of plugin for the browser and even then it would be difficult to accomplish. Generally browsers take specific care to *prevent* exactly what you want to do; that is, act as the user. Might be easier just to copy whatever it is to the clipboard and show users a screenshot of pasting things into the right location.

Comment: (Oh, and "native C++" is the only thing that's C++. There's a different language, C++/CLI, which looks similar but is really a completely different language which shares C++'s syntax, but has more in common with C#)

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to package the code that reads the smart card into an ActiveX control, then write some Javascript to call the control to retrieve the ID card data, and populate the fields in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You wrap the functionality of reading the smart card as an ActiveX control, and export the necessary methods that will allow the form to query the control. At the form, write Javascript that will instantiate the ActiveX control, based on its GUID, and call your exported methods to retrieve the data from the smart card and populate the form.

For this to work, you need to allow IE to run ActiveX controls (by default this is disabled), and also install the control. You can also make it simple for your user to download the control from your server by providing a link if the control cannot be instantiated.

You may also use Javascript to trigger when the ActiveX control signals and event (for example card insertion), but that's optional.